# Sort JSONArray with single for loop

Tags: java, json

I have a JSONArray with 5 different JSONObject and each of the 5 JSONObject has an identifier string value. The five values are "aa","bb","erer","cc","gg". My requirement is to get the JSONObject with identifier "erer" to first place and the following JSONObjects can be in any order.
The json is:

```
{
"obj":[
{"identifier":"aa",},
{"identifier":"bb",},
{"identifier":"erer",},
{"identifier":"cc",},
{"identifier":"gg",}
]
}
```

The final result has to be "erer","aa","bb","cc","gg" and I need to do this in a single loop.

I'm able to do this in two loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject j = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); 
     if(j.getString("identifier").equals("erer")) {
     sortedJson.put(joPayLoad);
}
}
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject j = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); 
     if(!j.getString("identifier").equals("erer")) {
     sortedJson.put(joPayLoad);
}
}
```

But the JsonArrray might also have 10,000 JSONObjects. And so, this 'two for-loops' will cause a performance lag. So, please help me to achieve my above said requirement in a single loop.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you could go for two lists, one where you put all the `erer`-Objects and one with the rest and then simply concat them after running through the for-loop once. If you use Java you could also use `addFirst` or `addLast` depending on the object you are handling. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) for these methods

Comment: what type is `sortedJson` and `jsonArray`?

Comment: Try debugging you will get the solution easily, looks like it is home work problem.

Comment: Thanks, Rugder. But I need to store the sorted objects in a jsonArray.

Comment: Hi Thomas, sortedJson is a JSONArray. and jsonArray is the JSON having those 5 objects.

Comment: yeah I can read that, but where do they come from? JavaSE doesn't have that in its API.

Comment: It's coming from a server.

Comment: He provided an example that does what he wants. It moves the "erer" elements to the front while leaving the order of the remaining elements unchanged. He just wants to do it in one loop. See my answer below.

Comment: It's not mandatory to sort the other jsonobjects. My requirement is to get "erer" to first place and the following elements can be like "gg","aa","cc","bb". It doesn't matter.

Comment: is there only one "erer" or multiple?

Comment: Only one "erer"

Comment: I apologize, GhostCat. No excuses. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @imrsk so did we solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah, your answer and Willis Blackburn answer are both correct.  I wish I can mark both the answer as correct. Thanks a lot for your time, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `JsonArray` is a List ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html)) you can just try to swap the value with `erer` to be the new first element:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     JsonValue j = jsonArray.get(i); 
     if(j.getString("identifier").equals("erer")) {
        JsonValue tmp = jsonArray.get(0);
        jsonArray.set(0, j);
        jsonArray.set(i, tmp);
        break;
     }
}
```

Haven't tried it since I don't have EE installed, but maybe you can make it work with the methods provided.

Comment: This isn't the same as his two-loop example, which can handle any number of "erer" elements.

Comment: true, but from the question it *sounds* like there is only one and that should be *the first* element.

Answer (score 1):

You need two pointers, a read pointer and a write pointer. Both start at the last item. Read the element at the read pointer. If it's "erer," then just decrement the read pointer, otherwise, write the element to the write pointer and decrease both the read pointer and the write pointer. At some point the read pointer will decrease to zero. If the write pointer is >0 it means you found some "erer" elements that you did not write. Write them to the write pointer and decrement the write pointer until it too is zero.

```
String[] data = { "aa", "gg", "dd", "ee", "erer", "gg", "erer" };

int r = data.length - 1, w = data.length - 1;
while (r >= 0) {
    if (!"erer".equals(data[r])) {
        data[w] = data[r];
        w--;
    }
    r--;
}
while (w >= 0) {
    data[w] = "erer";
    w--;
}
```

Okay, technically there's still two loops here, but it should be clear that we're iterating only once over the array. If you really gotta have one loop, this would work...

```
int r = data.length - 1, w = data.length - 1;
while (w >= 0) {
    if (r >= 0) {
        if (!"erer".equals(data[r])) {
            data[w--] = data[r];
        }
        r--;
    } else {
        data[w--] = "erer";
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged `Java`, not `JavaScript`.

Comment: You're right! That's funny, I wrote it in Java and actually converted into JS because I thought that's what he was using.

Comment: Also, I'm "sorting" strings, not JSONObject instances. But the point is to illustrate the loop. The OP knows how to use JSONObject.